# interceptor for Multiple file upload of different types

Tags: struts2

I have created two different file upload. One for media type and one for image type in the same form. How should I write interceptor in struts.xml so that it allows only media upload in mediaFileUpload and images in imageFileUpload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to validate against each file's mime type in the action's `validate` method (or in the `execute` method itself, although IMO that's doing the work in the wrong place).

See the [file types section in the file upload docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/file-upload.html#FileUpload-FileTypes). In a nutshell, each file's mime type is set with `setXxxContentType` (where `xxx` is the file property name). The mime type properties can be compared against your allowed types in `validate`.

Answer (score 0):

Create you own custom [interceptor stack](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/interceptors.html#Interceptors-FrameworkInterceptors) and configure them as per your requirement.You need to follow these steps

1. Create custom interceptor stack
2. Configure custom stack as per your requirement

Comment: can you please provide an example.

Comment: follow this tutorial, it will help you (http://www.vitarara.org/cms/struts_2_cookbook/creating_a_login_interceptor).Else see inside the struts2-core jar file and you will see how struts-default stack has been configured